# How to rewrite a directory to a cookie value in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, mod-rewrite

```
$val = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 12)), 0, 12);
setcookie('sub' , $val , time() + (86400) , '/');
```

`example.com/folder/file.php` should be rewritten to the value of `$_COOKIE['sub']` e.g. `example.com/6df1fcb7aba6/file.php`

How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*sub.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*sub.*$/(.*) folder/$1
```

, but doesn't work

Comment: What have you tried? Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: @MrWhite I have completely no idea how to do that, but here's edit

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:^|;|\s)sub=([a-z0-9]{12})(?:$|;)
RewriteRule ^folder/(file\.php)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

The above states:

1. Given a request for `/folder/file.php`
2. And the cookie `sub` exists with a 12 char alphanumeric (lowercase) value.
3. Rewrite the request to `/<sub-cookie-value>/file.php`

The `%1` backreference contains the value of the `sub` cookie, providing it meets the criteria of being a 12 char alphanumeric (lowercase) value.

The `$1` backreference simply contains `file.php` as captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*sub.*$ [NC]
> RewriteRule %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*sub.*$/(.*) folder/$1
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) is a regex that matches against the requested URL-path, so `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` (seen as a literal string) will never match, so the rule does nothing. However, the syntax of the 3rd argument (*flags*) is entirely invalid so is likely to result in a 500 Internal Server Error ("bad flags delimiter").

The `RewriteCond` directive is checking that the string `sub` does *not* occur anywhere in the `Cookie` HTTP request header, which is not what you want to do. You need to check that `sub` is present *and* extract the value.

Comment: that doesn't work. After the cookie sub is set and I give the request: `"example.com/".$_COOKIE['sub']."/file.php"` the 404 error is thrown

Comment: @Kyansittha What URL does that resolve to? What are you expecting to happen when you make that request? The code in my answer focuses on what you are asking in the question... it _internally rewrites_ the request _from_ `/folder/file.php` to `/<cookie-value>/file.php`. It does nothing with a request of the form `/<cookie-value>/file.php`, which you are perhaps expecting, but that is not what you have asked in the question. Admittedly, your question would seem incomplete - I'm assuming you had a physical directory with the value of the cookie - maybe that is not the case?